# Suppress Process Popup in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, popup, suppress

Our user panel runs all of our software as services. For whatever reason though, the Mumble voice software creates a popup when you run it with an administrator password set in the command line. Someone posted an alternative by using a bat file that runs two processes as a work around, but is there any way to just suppress the popup message using .NET? I have written a lot of launcher type apps to fix things like this, but I have no idea how I could suppress this message.

Here is what the .bat file looks like from the workaround.

```
set /p VAR= < superadmin.txt
start murmur2.exe -supw %var%
ping 0.0.0.0 -n 3 > NUL
tskill murmur2
murmur.exe
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to monitor open windows and close popup via winapi when it shows up

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

public const int WM_COMMAND = 0x0112;
public const int WM_CLOSE = 0xF060;

int handle = FindWindow(lpClassName, lpWindowName);
SendMessage(handle, WM_COMMAND, WM_CLOSE, 0);
```